# convergence of series with positive terms

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I am working on some calc2 convergence of series with positive terms online homework and I am having a particularly difficult time with this one problem. I solved the integral to be $\frac{-2}{15(x^3+4)^{5/2}}$, but I do not know how to fully evaluate that from 17 to infinity. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with is problem!

Comment: Honestly, who really cares what this integral (despite being an easy substitution evaluates to? The answer is meaningless. We know it is bounded by $x^2/(x^3)^{7/2} = 1/x^{17/2} \leq 1/x^2$. This integral evaluates to $1 - 1/17 = 16/17$. It is clearly bounded. As for your answer, you should get a positive answer; that is $2/15 \cdot \frac{1}{(17^3+4)^{5/2}} > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(a) - F(b)$$ where $F' = f$

In the case of indefinite intervals, if f(x) is continuos that is just

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{x \to b} F(x) - \lim_{x \to a} F(x)$$

It should be clear now how to evaluate it ;-)

Otherwise leave a comment with your problem ;)

Comment: if the integral is from 17 to infinity, wouldn't that just end up being [the limit of x->infinity of -2/(15(x^3+4)^(5/2))] - [the limit of x-> 17 of -2/(15(x^3+4)^(5/2))] which would be -7.8648096?

Comment: yes. The first addendum clearly goes to $0$, and the second evaluates to that value.  (Note that $F(x)$ is continuos so if $a \neq \infty$, $\lim_{x\to a} F(x) = F(a)$).
If you've liked the answer please accept it (http://math.stackexchange.com/about) by clicking the check below the vote count :)

Comment: The thing is webworks won't accept -7.8648096 as a correct answer so I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: The answer is clearly positive; you are off by sign.